# Как реализовать Autocomplete

Tags: javascript

таблица

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><?php echo $text_product_name; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_model; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_price; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_count; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_in_total; ?></th>
            <th> <a id="add_row" class="pull-left"><i  class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <!--<th class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="product_name" id="tags" required class="form-control">
            </th>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="model_product" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td >
              <input type="text" name="total" required class="form-control" id="i1"  onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'>
            </td>
            <td >
              <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png" border="0" onclick="jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); simplecheckout_reload(this);">
              <input type="text" name="quantity" id=i2  value="1" size="1" onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'>
              <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png" border="0" onclick="jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);simplecheckout_reload(this);">
            </td>
            <td >
              <input type="number" name="oll_total" id=i3>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>-->
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var flowers = ["Астра", "Нарцисс", "Роза", "Пион", "Примула",
    "Подснежник", "Мак", "Первоцвет", "Петуния", "Фиалка"];

var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='text'  id='tags' name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form-control'></td>" +
            "<td><input name='model_product[]' type='text'  class='form-control' /></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' required class='form-control' id='i1'  onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'></td>" +
            "<td><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1); simplecheckout_reload(this);'>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity[]' id=i2  value='1' size='1' onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'>" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick='jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);simplecheckout_reload(this);'></td>" +
            "<td><input type='text' name='oll_total[]' id=i3></td>" +
            "<td><a id='delete_row' style='margin-right:30%;' class='pull-right minus'><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i > 1 ){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: flowers
    });
});
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
  jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove();});

  function simplecheckout_reload(element){
    var row = $(element).closest("tr");

    var n1 = row.find("input[name='total[]']").val();
    var n2 = row.find("input[name='quantity[]']").val();
    row.find("input[name='oll_total[]']").val(Number(n1) * Number(n2));
}
```

получается при нажатие на плюс выпадает форма с полями, хочу сделать что в поле

```
<input type='text'  id='tags' name='product_name[]' autocomplete='on' required class='form-control'></td>" +
```

при воде выводились список товаров, если  делать это в самой таблице

```
              <input type="text" name="product_name" id="tags" required class="form-control">
```

то список повыпадает, а в первом варианте нет, не подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже объясняли про выборку по `id`.

`class='tags' // везде вместо id='tags'`

`$('.tags').autocomplete({source: flowers});`

```
$("#add_row").click(function(){
  ...
  $('#addr'+i).find('.tags').autocomplete({source: flowers});
  i++;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо понял, забыл про id